# Url malformed using symfony command

Tags: symfony

I have an error when I try to run a symfony2 command to import data :

> url malformed

Perhaps is caused because I try to import youtube data like that :

```
private function importYoutubeMedia(Block $block, TemplateEvenement $template)
    {
        // TODO : Fix Youtube Media issue
        $mediaManager = $this->container->get('sonata.media.manager.media');
        $media = new Media();
        $mediaBlock = new PageMedia();

        $media->setName($template->getTitle());
        $media->setBinaryContent($template->getYoutube());
        $media->setProviderReference($template->getYoutube());
        $media->setProviderStatus(1);
        $media->setContext('media');
        $media->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.youtube');

        $mediaManager->save($media);

        $mediaBlock->setMedia($media);
        $mediaBlock->setBlock($block);
        $block->addMedia($mediaBlock);

        $this->defaultEm->persist($mediaBlock);
        $this->defaultEm->persist($block);

        return $block;
    }
```

I configured my yml with

```
connector: sonata.media.buzz.connector.curl
```

but the problem persist in command not in sonata bundle interface.